# Overlaying a struct onto a u_char pointer

Tags: c++, casting, struct

My professor has instructed me that we can lay a struct over (casting) the pointer in memory we are getting in order to more easily interpret the data. I asked about this in class today and this is what he said would work.

This is not compiling complaining about how it can't cast it.
What am I doing wrong? I am about to resort to parsing the data manually...

```
struct DataStruct
{
    u_char DEST_ADDRESS[6];
    u_char SOURCE_ADDRESS[6];
};

struct DataStruct* testData;
testData = (struct DataStruct*)pkt_data;
```

Comment: What error does the compiler give you? Can you construct a complete (but small) test case that doesn't depend on anything unstated/left-out?

Comment: How do you have a 6 byte address? Is that a 48-bit architecture?

Comment: @Tarydon - MAC addresses (either Ethernet, 802.11, etc.) are 48 bits.

Comment: What's the data type of `pkt_data`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an statement outside of a function.

Change:

```
struct DataStruct* testData;               // definition okay outside function
testData = (struct DataStruct*)pkt_data;   // statement not okay outside function
```

to:

```
struct DataStruct* testData = (struct DataStruct*)pkt_data;  // definition with
                                                             // initializer okay
                                                             // outside function
```